# Route and view naming conventions

Tags: laravel, naming-conventions

I am looking for some input regarding the naming conventions I use for route names and view directory structures.

Say I have the following routes:

```
Route::get('/teams/choose', 'ChooseTeamController@index')->name('teams.choose.index');

Route::post('/teams/choose', 'ChooseTeamController@choose')->name('teams.choose');

Route::get('/teams/{team}/manage', 'ManageTeamController@index')->name('teams.team.manage.index');
```

For the `get` routes, I would nornally put the views in a directory structure matching the route name. E.g. `resources/views/teams/team/manage/index.blade.php`. However, I feel that this is way too verbose.

I feel that it would be confusing all round (to myself and other developers) if I was to use a view directory structure like so, rather than the last example: `resources/views/team/manage/index.blade.php`- the plural of `team` is not used, so when I have other views, like so (using the original examples convention): `resources/views/teams/choose.index` they dont visually have the relationship intended. I.e. they have a differing 'root' directory- `teams` vs `team`.

Any input or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> For the `get` routes, I would normally put the views in a directory structure matching the route name. E.g. `resources/views/teams/team/manage/index.blade.php`. However, I feel that this is way too verbose.

I agree.

---

From the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers):

Laravel uses the typical RESTful "CRUD" approach when assigning resource routes to a controller. Each **verb** (i.e. GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) gets a designated **URI**, an **action** (technically, a controller method) and a **route-name** (sometimes, `/path/to/blade/view`).

So, from your snippet:

```
// return view(teams.index)
Route::get('/teams', 'TeamController@index');

// return view(teams.create)
Route::get('/teams/create', 'TeamsController@create');

// redirect('/home');
Route::post('/teams', 'TeamController@store');

// return view('teams.profile')
Route::get('/teams/profile', 'TeamController@profile')->name('profile');
```

---

I use this [resource table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers) to remind me what-to-do and what-not-do all the time.

Perhaps, inspecting some of the [awesome Laravel codebases](https://github.com/chiraggude/awesome-laravel#codebases-for-reference), might help. Plus, a perspective on how other teams are doing things is always priceless.

I found these to be very helpful:

- [RESTful API Best Practices and Common Pitfalls](https://medium.com/@schneidenbach/restful-api-best-practices-and-common-pitfalls-7a83ba3763b5#.87s6inoea)
- [RESTful API Design - A Cookbook](https://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html)

---

**Update**

The key is to stick to the standard CRUD actions i.e. index, show, create, store, edit, update and delete. The views will fall, right into their place.

Check out [Adam Wathan's talk at Laracon EU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF0jFKvS4SI) as he demonstrates how, **anything can be CRUDDY** with a little imagination.

Answer (score 4):

There are so many ways to maintain routes based on the requirement but i always follow below guidelines which helps me to maintain the file structure and easy to understand.

```
//listing
Route::get('/teams', 'TeamController@index');

//Create
Route::get('/teams/create', 'TeamController@create');

//Store
Route::post('/teams/store', 'TeamController@store');

//Show
Route::get('/teams/{id}', 'TeamController@show');

//Edit
Route::get('/teams/{id}/edit', 'TeamController@edit');

//Update
Route::put('/teams/{id}/update', 'TeamController@update');

//Delete
Route::delete('/teams/{id}/delete', 'TeamController@delete');
```

for more information related to proper naming convention you may follow below link

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#restful-nested-resources

Comment: Do not use verbs in routes, instead of
`Route::delete('/teams/{id}/delete', 'TeamController@delete');` use
`Route::delete('/teams/{id}', 'TeamController@delete');`

Answer (score 0):

if you are building with consuming by api as a concern, you wouldn't need the `create` and `edit` forms so endpoints can be reduced to:

```
//listing
Route::get('/teams', 'TeamController@index');

//Store
Route::post('/teams', 'TeamController@store');

//Show
Route::get('/teams/{id}', 'TeamController@show');

//Update
Route::put('/teams/{id}', 'TeamController@update');

//Delete
Route::delete('/teams/{id}', 'TeamController@delete');
```