# Laravel route goes for another page instead of correct one

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Goes on another route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('/employees', [App\Http\Controllers\AngajatiController::class, 'show'])->name('employees');
    Route::get('/show-form', [App\Http\Controllers\AngajatiController::class, 'show_form'])->name('show-form');
    Route::post('/show-form', [App\Http\Controllers\AngajatiController::class, 'add_employee'])->name('add-employee');
    Route::post('/delete-employee', [App\Http\Controllers\AngajatiController::class, 'delete_employee'])->name('delete-employee');
    Route::get('/{slug}', [App\Http\Controllers\AngajatiController::class, 'see_employee'])->name('see-employee');
    Route::put('/{slug}', [App\Http\Controllers\AngajatiController::class, 'update_employee'])->name('update-employee');
    Route::post('/search-employee', [App\Http\Controllers\SearchController::class, 'search_employee'])->name('search-employee');
});

Route::get('/generate-pdf', [App\Http\Controllers\GeneratePDF::class, 'show_pdf'])->name('generate-pdf');
```

This is `generatepdf.php`

```
public function show_pdf(Request $request){
    return view('tAngajati.genereaza-pdf');
}
```

I have an employees table, where I have a View button, next to a Generate PDF button. When I press the View button it goes on SLUG route in (`see-employees.blade.php`). When I press Generate PDF I have a separate controller and a separate function (I have returned the view `tAngajati.genereaza-pdf`) but the problem is it is not going to `genereaza-pdf.blade.php`, it goes for `see-employees.blade.php` and it throws error that I don't have defined some values (based on employee details).

Comment: put the `generate-pdf` route declaration above the slug one. Or a better solution would be to change the slug one to `employee/{slug}` so the routes that get cought by that route need to have the prefix `employee`

Comment: You will have the same problem with the `search-employee` route because `search-employee` might also match a `{slug}`

Comment: Use REST routes and forget about these route issues.  Delete /employees/{id}; GET /employees/{id}; PUT, PATCH for the same routes. POST /employees means create new one

Comment: thank you guys. problem solved. i just made another routes like @N69S said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the way you structure your routes so that they follow a more standardized approach. That will prevent you from getting in trouble again since this is a common issue.

The thing is that you have:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', [App\Http\Controllers\AngajatiController::class, 'see_employee'])->name('see-employee');
```

and

```
Route::get('/generate-pdf', [App\Http\Controllers\GeneratePDF::class, 'show_pdf'])->name('generate-pdf');
```

And Laravel is treating the "generate-pdf" as just another slug and is therefore redirecting it to the route you mentioned

Quick and dirty solution would be to change how your generate-pdf route is defined, for example:

```
Route::get('/pdf/generate', [App\Http\Controllers\GeneratePDF::class, 'show_pdf'])->name('generate-pdf');
```

Because it would have two segments (pdf and generate) to it in difference to other routes, it would work fine. But I would recomment you restructure all of you routes like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415148/route-and-view-naming-conventions) for example so that you follow common good practices